# C# Adding Hyperlinks Does Not Work If Cell Value Has Spaces

Tags: c#, .net, hyperlink, vsto

I am attempting to add a hyperlink to an Excel cell using C#.  I am very close to having the syntax perfect, however my issue is that the value from the corresponding cell is not added to the hyperlink.  Meaning, let's say that the variable `cellVale = Red` well when the hyperlink is added the syntax below only adds the !A1 **NOT** the Red!A1

What should I alter in this syntax so that valid hyperlinks are created?

```
    lr = WS.Cells[WS.Rows.Count, 2].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
for (i = 2; i <= lr; i++)
{
    cellVal = WS.Cells[i, 1].Value;
    rangeToHoldHyperlink = WS.Range["I" + i];
    if (cellVal == "*,*" || cellVal == "*'*" || cellVal == "*&*" || cellVal == "*-*" || cellVal == "*.*")
        _Excel.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(rangeToHoldHyperlink, "", "'" + cellVal + "!A1", "");
    else
        _Excel.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(rangeToHoldHyperlink, "", cellVal + "!A1", "");
}
```

**EDIT**
One thing I just noticed is that the "hover text", meaning if I hover the mouse over the cell it shows the valid hyperlink reference, i.e. Red!A1, but this is not added to the click event if I click.  Did I inaccurately set-up the `Hyperlinks.Add` Metho?d
**EDIT 2**
I slightly altered my syntax following the [MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.hyperlinks.add.aspx) to this

```
_Excel.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(rangeToHoldHyperlink, "'" + cellVal + "!A1", "", "");
```

Which set's the appropriate reference Red!A1 **BUT** it adds `%` sign in any spaces which invalidates the worksheet name reference.  How can I have C# NOT add a % sign in any spaces in the above syntax?

**Edit 3**
I just realized that I had not posted my code I tried after using the macro recorder to attempt to remedy this.  The syntax below works if the text in column A has no spaces or special characters.  If it does contain those fields, I continue to get the Invalid Reference error.

Syntax:

```
Object Anchor = WS.Cells[i, 9];
Object TextToDisplay = Convert.ToString(WS.Cells[i, 9]);
cellVal = WS.Cells[i, 1].Value;
rangeToHoldHyperlink = WS.Range["I" + i];
_Excel.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor, "", "'" + cellVal + "'!A1", "", TextToDisplay);
```

This is the VBA syntax that works perfectly in EXCEL, that I tried to convert to the above syntax, but for some reason in C# (or my conersion) it does not work like i need it to.  Did I incorrectly convert something?

**Working VBA**

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Cells(i, 9), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & WS.Cells(i, 1).Value & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=CStr(WS.Cells(i, 9))
```

**Edit 4**
My updated syntax from Edit 3 will work if the value in cell A1 (or i,1) is one word with no comma or hyphen.  If the value has a comma or hyphen it will not work.
**Works**

```
Red - value variable produces is string help2 = cellVal + "!A1"; = Red!A1
Green - value variable produces is string help2 = cellVal + "!A1"; =   Green!A1
Blue - value variable produces is string help2 = cellVal + "!A1"; = Blue!A1
```

**Does Not Work**

```
Red And Yellow - value variable produces is string help2 = cellVal + "!A1"; = Red And Yellow!A1
Pink And Blue - value variable produces is string help2 = cellVal + "!A1"; = Pink And Blue!A1
```

Comment: I am testing to see if I can come up with a resolution.  One thing I notice right off is that "'" + cellVal + "!A1" should be "'" + cellVal + "'!A1" - You are missing your closing single quote before the !

Comment: Just some general advice.  Try using the Excel macro recorder to obtain the general syntax for the command.  Typically, it will yield code that is 90% or better towards a valid programming command.

Comment: @TnTinMn - the sample syntax from my Edit 2 is what I translated from the macro recorder.  Thank you for the idea

Comment: When I record it I get: `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Sheet 2'!A1", TextToDisplay:="'Sheet 2'!A1"`.  As C# it would be:  `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:Selection, Address:"", SubAddress: "'Sheet 2'!A1", TextToDisplay:"'Sheet 2'!A1");`.   Just need to correct the Anchor argument.

Comment: @TnTinMn - my apology you are 100% correct.  I thought I had posted an updated code, but I had not. Please see my edit #3 code.  Close but not quite there.

Comment: @TnTinMn - I just created VBA code that works as it should, and to me it looks exactly like my C# syntax.  However, the C# syntax does not work, do you see any issues?

Comment: As you have made changes to your original code, is the issue still the % symbol instead of spaces or is something new?  As a diagnostic test, assign the result of `"'" + cellVal + "'!A1"` to a string variable and set a breakpoint to inspect the result.  Also, was the original issue just adding a % or possibly %20 that would indicate that it is passing a Html encoding for a space.

Comment: @TnTinMn - the original issue was that it would add %20 - good catch.  I  have updated with Edit #4 that I believe clearly describes what the current issue is, and what is produced if I assign to a string variable per your comment above.

Comment: I think you may be back to the problem of not surrounding the Worksheet name with a single quote character.  i.e.: `string help2 = "'" + cellVal + "'!A1";`

Comment: @TnTinMn -> that was it, the missing single quote, thank you!